# The following error log create when we upgrade the website. How to solve it?

Tags: magento

{"0":"Warning: include(/home/healthba/public_html/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/base/templates/root.phtml): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/healthba/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php on line 326","1":"#0 /home/healthba/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(326): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'include(/home/h...', '/home/healthba/...', 326, Array)\n#1 /home/healthba/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(326): include()\n#2 /home/healthba/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(259): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->renderPage()\n#3 /home/healthba/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php(170): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))\n#4 /home/healthba/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))\n#5 /home/healthba/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', Array)\n#6 /home/healthba/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))\n#7 /home/healthba/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(130): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', Array, Array)\n#8 /home/healthba/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(139): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))\n#9 /home/healthba/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()\n#10 /home/healthba/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(257): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()\n#11 /home/healthba/public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))\n#12 {main}","url":"/?SID=p99e91ftftrn8vrmfnutdv01l6","script_name":"/index.php"}

Answer (score 0):

Did you login as root in SSH? This could cause issues in your file permissions. Please try this: [Magento 2 -- debug.log -- main.DEBUG: Request validation failed for action "Vendor\Module\Controller\Index\Post\Interceptor"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58439835/magento-2-debug-log-main-debug-request-validation-failed-for-action-vend/58440024?noredirect=1#comment103221278_58440024)