# Magento 2 -- debug.log -- main.DEBUG: Request validation failed for action "Vendor\Module\Controller\Index\Post\Interceptor"

Tags: php, validation, post, module, magento2

I'm implementing a Custom Module that essentially has the same functionality as the default Magento 2 Contact Form. I'm receiving a very irritating error I can't seem to find a solution to. It seems my POST request is failing Magento's request validation, but I'm not sure how to find any more specific information.

I've attempted to implement a "CSRFSkip" plugin that bypasses the Magento CSRF validation. I've tried changing what my controller extends and implements. I've searched the logs extensively.

Here's my Magento debug.log as the error is happening.

```
[2019-10-17 19:39:16] main.DEBUG: Request validation failed for action "Vendor\Module\Controller\Index\Post\Interceptor" [] []
[2019-10-17 19:41:20] main.DEBUG: Request validation failed for action "Vendor\Module\Controller\Index\Post\Interceptor" [] []
[2019-10-17 19:41:21] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2019-10-17 19:41:21] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2019-10-17 19:41:21] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
```

Here's my controller. /Vendor/Module/Controller/Index/Post.php

```php
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Post extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action implements \Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface
{
    /**
     * Post action
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        if (!$post['name']) {
            $this->_redirect('/find-a-dealer');
            return;
        }

        $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
        try {
            $postObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
            $postObject->setData($post);
            $error = false;

            $this->logger->debug($post['name']);
            if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['name']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }

            $this->logger->debug($post['email']);
            if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['email']), 'EmailAddress')) {
                $error = true;
            }

            $this->logger->debug($post['city']);
            if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['city']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }

            $this->logger->debug($post['state']);
            if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['state']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }

            $this->logger->debug($post['zip']);
            if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['zip']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }

            $this->logger->debug($post['part']);
            if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['part']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }

            if ($error) {
                throw new \Exception();
            }

            $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
            $transport = $this->_transportBuilder
                ->setTemplateIdentifier($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, $storeScope))
                ->setTemplateOptions(
                    [
                        'area' => \Magento\Backend\App\Area\FrontNameResolver::AREA_CODE,
                        'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
                    ]
                )
                ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObject])
                ->setFrom($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER, $storeScope))
                ->addTo($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT, $storeScope))
                ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
                ->getTransport();

            $transport->sendMessage();

            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(
                __('Thanks for contacting us with your comments and questions. We\'ll respond to you very soon.')
            );
            $this->getDataPersistor()->clear('find-a-dealer');
            $this->_redirect('find-a-dealer');
            return;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
            $this->messageManager->addError(
                __('We can\'t process your request right now. Sorry, that\'s all we know.')
            );
            $this->getDataPersistor()->set('find-a-dealer', $post);
            $this->_redirect('find-a-dealer');
            return;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get Data Persistor
     *
     * @return DataPersistorInterface
     */
    private function getDataPersistor()
    {
        if ($this->dataPersistor === null) {
            $this->dataPersistor = ObjectManager::getInstance()
                ->get(DataPersistorInterface::class);
        }

        return $this->dataPersistor;
    }
}
```

I expect for my post function to run and dispatch my email.

What actually happens is a redirect to my form page, and some validation related errors in the logs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't call the url from browser directly.
add it to a menu action link or to a button and call it from there.

OR

Disable the key in the admin and try.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it is the form_key. I've added form key input field explicitly in  and it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the permissions for var, generated and pub folders? When using root user for deploying changes the permissions can change to 644 causing these type of issues.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I've included the output of `ls -l` for each of those directories below!

drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant   4096 Oct 17 19:28 var
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant   4096 Oct 17 20:06 generated
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant   4096 Oct  8 23:46 pub

Comment: It seems ok. I did try 777 for those folders, in my case that worked. First I deleted pub/static/frontend and var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/frontend, then: php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento c:f
php bin/magento c:c, then checked the folder permissions. That got it working for me several times.

Comment: I'll try that as soon as I get back to my desk! Thank you again for your quick help!:)

Comment: I wanted to give you an update!
I now am actually receiving an exception, which is debuggable.
`1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined property: Parthenon\Find\Controller\Index\Post\Interceptor::$inlineTranslation in /srv/www/app/code/Parthenon/Find/Controller/Index/Post.php on line 22`
I'm going to try to tackle this one! Also, a million thanks!

Comment: That's great! Good luck :)